# Lightweight Migration working differently between OS X 10.9 and 10.11

Tags: xcode, cocoa, core-data

I have an App using Core Data and I have several builds versions along with different data model versions. My old MBP is Running OS X 10.9 and Xcode 6.1 - none of the App versions would do a backwards migration, which I planned for and coded a method to address it. My new MBP is running OSx10.11 and the latest Xcode. I moved my project over and created a build from Xcode 7 to start testing - one test is what happens with older version of the data model.

App V2 has a different data model version than V3 of the App. So here is what happened when testing.

On the new MBP (OS X 10.11) with a blank slate, I ran V3, added some data and saved. Then ran v2 and expected it no to read the datafile, then run a method to address the error. But to my surprise, it loaded the file - all the data was there! I can switch between V2 and V3 of my App and they will both open the same database without errors. Again V2 and V3 have different data model versions.

Next, I took the same App files and moved then to the old MBP (OSx10.9) and did the exact same test - V2 would NOT open the V3 datafile and launched the appropriate method I had setup.

I changed NO code after moving the project to the new system.

I've searched the webs and have not found anything on this - so has anyone experienced this or have some information?

Comment: Is this a consequence of the model caching introduced in iOS9 and OSx10.11? - see [the CoreData video from WWDC 2015](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-220/?time=1150) at about 19 minutes in.

Comment: I believe that is what I'm seeing - thanks for the info and link.